# Recovering From An SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql-injection

Let's not go so far as to say that I'm paranoid, but I've been spending hour after hour learning how to prevent SQL injections (and XSS for what it's worth).

What I'm wondering is that a SQL injection doesn't seem like it would do permanent harm to my database if I've made daily backups.  Doesn't importing yesterday's copy of my tables just restore them and then I can be on my merry way?

Comment: "SQL injection doesn't seem like it would do permanent harm to my database " - why treat the symptoms when you can treat the cause?

Comment: "if I've made daily backups"... that's like saying "well, the thief just opened my unlocked door and walked in and stole my tv. it's ok, I closed the door again and bought a new tv. I'll be fine now".

Comment: @marc, while I appreciate the analogy, it doesn't seem accurate.  I have daily digital copies of my database, so it's more like opening my backup folders and picking the latest version.

Comment: Well, let's say your injectable code is part of a credit card processing script. While I'm sure it's nice to be able to retrieve past transactions from your backups, some poor user will not appreciate having a 50 bajillion dollar charge show up on their statement because the "send to processor" query was subverted. It'll cost you far less, time-wise, to write proper inject-proof code in the first place, than it will to clean up after an injection attack.

Comment: Marc B, you're a very funny dude!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as actual loss of data goes, you're mostly correct - you'd lose any changes made in the past day, but aside from that you'd be back to a functional database.

However, there are other things that, just because they aren't "lost", doesn't mean it isn't bad that they got *compromised*. These kinds of things are stuff like user account info (and especially password hashes) - things that people use to protect their accounts and, if discovered by the wrong people, can lead to malicious usage of their information and resources.

That's why you have to work to avoid security breaches in the first place rather than simply rolling back any changes.

Comment: Thanks for answers from everyone.  While I haven't stopped preparing my site for attacks from attacks when we do go public, I was mostly concerned with the ability to recover.

The general idea that I got from these answers is that restoring backups is futile if the hacker got the information he wanted anyway. I'll still work hard to prevent unauthorized access.  But in the long run, I can sleep easier knowing that my website doesn't deal with tons of private date such as credit cards.  No one's real life will be affected, hopefully.

Comment: Not to try to scaremonger or anything, but if you *do* deal with at least user passwords, there's always the chance that the user uses the same password on multiple sites, and thus having such compromised can reveal more than just the data on your own site.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very dangerous way to think. Yes, SQL injection attacks will usually trash the database and thus instantly crash your web app, after which you (somewhat) merrily restore from backup and go on your (somewhat) merry way.

On the other hand, they may simply blow away or alter a few records at random, so that it takes you weeks or even months to discover that your data have been getting slowly corrupted over a long period of time. Good luck recovering from that.

Worse still, the SQL injection attack might be designed to steal data rather than damage it. An attacker might figure how to get your web site to deliver a bunch of credit card numbers in response to a nominal request to edit their profile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless the table contains user-sensitive and/or XSS-injected data. Then you've another problem to fix. Always [sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on SQL injections during constructing SQL queries and always [sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on XSS injections during displaying client-controlled data in HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have noted that you've partially addressed the issue of data *loss* (restore from hopefully recent backup) but missed the issue of data *theft*.

There's another potential issue.  Many SQL servers allow you to execute arbitrary system commands (e.g. [MS SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)).  Others (e.g. [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id3454291)) let you write arbitrary files (see also [this article](http://www.greensql.net/publications/backdoor-webserver-using-mysql-sql-injection) on exploiting MySQL injections).  The bottom line is that an SQL injection attack can compromise the whole system, and thence onward.  Of course, there are configuration options to disable some of these, but they're real concerns.

If you want recommendations, I suggest [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php).